# How can I replace these cross braces with something else so they can be removed?

Tags: structural, construction

We want to open this up for the view under the house but these braces are structural and I don't just want to remove them. Is there a way to change these up so we can remove the braces (and lattice)?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's on top??

Comment: Brace from the top corners to outside - ie triangles but that may be inconvenient as well.

Comment: If the structure above is independently braced you don't need the diagonals. Please provide more context.

Comment: Also, explain the basis for your assertion that the braces are structural. They look decorative to me, or merely structural with respect to the lattice.

Comment: Simply removing the lattice (and all the other stuff stored under there) will open up the view a fair bit. What are the spans (height x width) of the openings that are cross braced? If you can get us some close ups of the attachment of the cross bracing, that may help indicate whether they were structural or decorative.

Answer (score 0):

Use steel cables or rods to replace them. Same arrangement (actually better to go fully top and bottom, not stop short of the bottom as these do), but much thinner. Each cable or set of rods will need a turnbuckle to tighten it.

Comment: You'd have to explain how to attach them in a code-compliant manner for this to be viable.

Comment: However those cross braces operate in *both* compression *and* tension.  Cables and rods operate only in tension.  So you would need to replace that compressive strength with something. It could be a beam running along the top.

Comment: X-bracing - if one is in compression, the other is in tension. Practically speaking, if you have both parts of the X you don't need any compression (and given the slenderness ratio of the lumber at that length, you don't have *much* compression function anyway with the lumber as shown.)